# Diagram generator to enhance the Q&A editor?

Tags: discussion, feature-request

On our sibling site [Raspberry Pi Stack Exchange](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com) the Q&A editor has a build-in schematic drawing tool. Inspired by ["How do I add a schematic to my question?" - Raspberry Pi Meta Stack Exchange](https://raspberrypi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2074/how-do-i-add-a-schematic-to-my-question) I would like to ask here on Network Engineering Meta: Are we in need of a network specific drawing tool to enhance the editor?

Comment: I'm not really for or against this (if any suitable plugin would exist), but to make this a bit easier I've made two possible answers, so people can indicate their opinion just by upvoting.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, a plugin for adding diagrams would be useful (if possible and available).

Answer (score 0):

No, there are plenty of tools around for people to create their diagrams.

Comment: Serious question... Is there a negative side effect of a tool like this? I'm struggling to think a reason people would vote no to this addition.

Comment: One can be that there is no need for this site to do everything, it can be enough for people if it does one thing really well, which is be a Q&A platform. Too many additional features can make things confusing and bloated, and it could be a waste of time getting it to work if nobody will be using it. Depending on what tool is offered (if any is available) there could be consequences in who owns rights to generated images, or who is able to modify them.